# How to setStatus after timer.Elapsed

Tags: c#, timer

My question is probably quite simple. In a c# project i am trying to set a status of an instance in a different class at a `click` event. The trouble is that i want to do this after a certain time has elapsed and without any c# experience I find this quite hard to accomplish.

Thanks in advance!!

my code is as follows:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht1.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);
    kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht2.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);            
    this.Refresh();            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `async` (assuming you're using C# 5):

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(5));
    kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht1.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);
    kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht2.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);            
    this.Refresh();            
}
```

Another option is to use a `Timer`:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 5000 };
    timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht1.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);
        kruispunt.zPad1.voetstoplicht2.setStatus(StoplichtStatus.Rood);
        this.Refresh();
    }
    timer.Start();
}
```

Note that I used a Windows Forms timer, rather than `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`; this is because the event must occur in the UI thread, otherwise the call to `Refresh` would fail.